# How to use the ASP .NET AJAX Toolkit Tab with a Grid View inside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, datagridview, tabcontrol, multiview

I have already search for some time over the net on how to create an ASP .NET AJAX toolkit tab control which uses GridView inside, could anyone point me on how to do this?

Right now, our GUI team has already made a static tab control which is quite properly designed. I do not know how to use the tab with this. Any tutorial or link on using this combination could really help.

I am already converting back the GUI to a MultiView simulated tab control because I do not know how to access the tab control. anyway, I am just worried i would destroy the GUI made by GUI team in this process.

Thanks.

Comment: How would we be able to give a tutorial or link to a component that your in-house team has designed?

Comment: The in house gui is not a component. let us assume we use the prebuilt gridview in asp .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got this to work. Basically the Tab control is just a panel container that holds other AJAX control. Unlike the MultiView control which does a post back each time a new tab is clicked, the AJAX tab control allows the loading of lots of control to the client all at once.  The data grid control is used as is via post back. The only draw back of ajax tab control is the whole set of controls are loaded on each post back.